# How to write down a product with omitted terms?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation, products

I have the following term which I would like to express correctly in *Mathematica*:

$$
\prod_{j=1,j\neq i}^m(\rho_i-\rho_j)
$$

Can you please help?

Comment: The question is unclearly formulated. Is it a product by $j$ or by $i,j$?

Answer (score 6):

Long form:

```
Product[(ρ[i] - ρ[j]), {i, 1, m}, {j, i + 1, m}] Product[(ρ[i] - ρ[j]), {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, i - 1}]
```

By observing that each factor occurs twice (up to sign):

```
Product[ - (ρ[i] - ρ[j])^2, {i, 1, m}, {j, i + 1, m}]
```

By counting the signs:

```
(-1)^(m (m - 1)/2) Product[(ρ[i] - ρ[j])^2, {i, 1, m}, {j, i + 1, m}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You mean without the ^2 cous its not in the question, but it helped.

Comment: Yes the square is in the question: every term occurs twice (with opposite signs). There should be a $(-1)^{m(m-1)/2}$ factor too, to account for these signs.

Comment: @Roman Huh, I completely forgot about the sign. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
ClearAll[ prod]
prod[m_, i_] := Product[ρ[i] - ρ[j], {j, DeleteCases[Range[m], i]}]

prod[5, 2]
```

> (-ρ[1] + ρ[2]) (ρ[2] - ρ[3]) (ρ[2] - ρ[4]) (ρ[2] - ρ[5])